# How do you modify font attributes to make a font proportional in iOS?

Tags: ios, fonts, uifont

I have a running timer on a video in the format of 0:00:00. I want the characters 1-9 to all be the same width so that the label doesn't move around when the timer updates. I plucked this code from an apple slideshow but I am having no luck with it. Every character seems to be proportional except for "1". I'm having a hard time finding any examples or documentation about this. I'm calling `setFont` on a UILabel with the return value of the method below. The font I'm trying to use is GothamNarrow-Book. I pass in @"GothamNarrow-Book" to this method.

```
-(UIFont*) getProportionalFontForTimerWithFont:(NSString*)fontName WithRatio:(CGFloat) fontRatio{
    UIFont *const existingFont=[UIFont fontWithName:fontName];
    UIFontDescriptor *const existingDescriptor=[existingFont fontDescriptor];

    NSDictionary *const timeFeatureSettings=@{
                                         UIFontDescriptorFeatureSettingsAttribute:@[
                                                 @{

                                                     UIFontFeatureTypeIdentifierKey: @(kNumberSpacingType),
                                                     UIFontFeatureSelectorIdentifierKey:@(kProportionalNumbersSelector)
                                                     },
                                                 @{
                                                     UIFontFeatureTypeIdentifierKey: @(kCharacterAlternativesType),
                                                     UIFontFeatureSelectorIdentifierKey:@(1)
                                                     }]
                                         };

    UIFontDescriptor *const proportionalDescriptor=[existingDescriptor fontDescriptorByAddingAttributes:timeFeatureSettings];
    UIFont* proportionalFont=[UIFont fontWithDescriptor:proportionalDescriptor size:[existingFont pointSize]];

    return proportionalFont;

}
```

Comment: Why not use a proportional font, such as `Menlo`?

Comment: The same font is being used everywhere in the app as a design decision. I would like to use it here as well, but will have to switch if I can't figure this out.

Comment: I think the problem is the font might not have a proportional alternatives. Which font are you using?

Comment: I"m using GothamNarrow-Book

Comment: You are using the word "proportional" incorrectly. You want the _opposite_ of proportional, i.e. you want monospace. See e.g. http://home.myfairpoint.net/vzenu5ot/portfolio/sg_items/mono_propor_font_example.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was misunderstanding what proportional meant. Changing the key from proportional to monospaced fixed my issue.

```
-(UIFont*) getProportionalFontForTimerWithFont:(NSString*)fontName WithRatio:(CGFloat) fontRatio{
    UIFont *const existingFont=[UIFont fontWithName:fontName];
    UIFontDescriptor *const existingDescriptor=[existingFont fontDescriptor];

    NSDictionary *const timeFeatureSettings=@{
                                         UIFontDescriptorFeatureSettingsAttribute:@[
                                                 @{

                                                     UIFontFeatureTypeIdentifierKey: @(kNumberSpacingType),
                                                     UIFontFeatureSelectorIdentifierKey:@(kMonospacedNumbersSelector)
                                                     },
                                                 @{
                                                     UIFontFeatureTypeIdentifierKey: @(kCharacterAlternativesType),
                                                     UIFontFeatureSelectorIdentifierKey:@(1)
                                                     }]
                                         };

    UIFontDescriptor *const proportionalDescriptor=[existingDescriptor fontDescriptorByAddingAttributes:timeFeatureSettings];
    UIFont* proportionalFont=[UIFont fontWithDescriptor:proportionalDescriptor size:[existingFont pointSize]];

    return proportionalFont;

}
```

Comment: You could also use the `NSFontMonoSpaceTrait` trait with the font descriptor. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Since you're always drawing a fixed number of characters why not just position and draw each one by hand? You could even make each one it's own UILabel or other control.

Answer (score 0):

Step one: pin the label

Just use auto layout to pin the height and width and the bottom right corner. This will insure that your label does not move.

Step two: modify the font

In storyboard, set auto shrink property of the UILabel to minimum font scale. Then set the % size that you want and you should be good to go.

Comment: I think the label is probably not moving technically, just the width of the characters not being proportional is causing the text to shift left and right. Also, I'm not using storyboard, but I'll look into that.